# WebGL - How to pass program parameter to gl.attachShader correctly in Typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, webgl

I create a program like so:

```
const program: WebGLProgram = gl.createProgram();
```

Then eventually attempt to attach the shader to the program like so:

```
gl.attachShader(program, vertexShader);
```

This throws the following error:

> Error: TypeError: Failed to execute 'attachShader' on 'WebGL2RenderingContext': parameter 1 is not of type 'WebGLProgram'.

Upon observing the program, `typeof program` is equal to `object`, so the error makes sense.

If I try and do the following, which works if I change the program type to any since `typeof program.program` is equal to `WebGLProgram`:

```
gl.attachShader(program.program, vertexShader);
```

It will throw the following error:

> Property 'program' does not exist on type 'WebGLProgram'.

What is the correct way to resolve this issue in Typescript? I would prefer not to write `program.program` with the any type.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The error is not thrown by the TypeScript compiler, it is thrown by the browser runtime. If `strictNullChecks` is enabled in the `tsconfig.json` `compilerOptions`, you'll see the return type of [WebGLRenderingContext/createProgram](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebGLRenderingContext/createProgram)  is `WebGLProgram | null`, then you must first check that `program` is not null:

```js
const canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
const gl = canvas.getContext("webgl");
if (gl) {
  const program = gl.createProgram();
  const vertexShader = gl.createShader(gl.VERTEX_SHADER);
  if (program && vertexShader) {
    gl.attachShader(program, vertexShader);
  } else {
    throw new Error("WebGL createProgram or createShader failed!");
  }
} else {
  throw new Error("WebGL seems not supported!");
}
```

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/MYewdgzgLgBMCGYBu8IwLwwCYmAVwFsBTMKAOmACcj4oiBRAGyONIAoAiBZVDgSgDcAKFCRYAc0YY4iFBDLiiUAMLg6ADyicA7kQBGk-sICWAMxhtJfGAG8hMOOGgwADpRDjK8AtMkVqtEQACu6e3myC9o5iMEhElBoAygAW8Fjxvoz+NHQpafGWWQBq9ABKACr0ABoA+okAEgCCACJlkQ5mFm4eXj4AZH2x8Ump6ZTWdg4OfrRQ8MDJeWNs3WEEADRDCUTqS-HtMAC+MESMEES2UQ5Qye7aMGBE9-SU7pScAOr6AOIAMnABOghHreGAgSgAnJEPYQ0zwYzMLAAQiMUUOQmOp3Ol2utxA90ez1e4M+P3+5xYaDAIFgEDwLhc4LoyNRhyAA)

Comment: Thanks, but this unfortunately does not resolve my issue. You're right, it's a browser runtime error, however I have `strictNullChecks` set to false. The issue does not appear to be related to the fact program might be null. It's related to the fact that program is type of object rather than WebGLProgram.

Comment: @Edward In JavaScript,  `typeof null === 'object'`, TypeScript is compiled to JavaScript.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, `typeof null === 'object'` is not something I was aware of.